# Call another controller and use a different Layout for the called controller action MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Am new to MVC ASP.Net. I would like to call an action method from another controller and use a different layout page.

My Views/Shared folder has two layout pages: ~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml and ~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml. Below is my code:

```
//HomeController
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
          //Call someMethod from UserController
          //And when called, it should a different Layout page: ~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml
          return View("someMethod"); 
        }
        else
        {
          return AboutPage(id); //uses ~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml
        }
     }
    public ActionResult AboutPage(string id)
    {
       return View();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different layout then you can use overloaded version of `View` method:

```
return View("view", "_Layout1");
```

If you want to redirect control flow to different controller/action then:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");
```

Comment: For the first case, do I have to specify path for the "view" and "_Layout1"? For some reason it can't find the layout page when I run the program. Thanks

Comment: `"_Layout2"` should work just fine, however you can try `"~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml"` instead of `"_Layout1"`. Check exception for paths which has been used to find master name (layout).

Comment: awesome! it works when its "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml". Thanks @walkhard :)

Comment: Another question if you don't mind. For the second case: is it possible to redirect control flow and use "_Layout2.cshtml as opposed to using regular "_Layout1.cshtml" ?

Comment: You will have to do this in another action, in the one which will return `View`.